# Connect hadoop in C#

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I want to connect hadoop in c# using HDInsight. I have created a cluster in AZURE and it was created successfully. and also I enabled remote desktop connection in it.
When I entered the credentials in C# and execute the job then I get the connection error. I am confused in providing the parameters. Kindly assist me.

```
var hadoop = Hadoop.Connect(new Uri("https://clustername.azurehdinsight.net"), "admin", "");
//I have set remote desktop password

var config = new HadoopJobConfiguration();



                config.InputPath = "input/CodeFiles";
                config.OutputFolder = "output/CodeFiles";
                var result = hadoop.MapReduceJob.ExecuteJob<NamespaceCounterJob>();
```

Last line gives the exception. 
Exception message is:

> One or more errors occured

And this is the inner exception:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: What exactly is the connection error?  I assume that you are providing a password, but just removing it in the code example?  Personally I change the password to something like MyPassword in a code sample to make it clear that it was provided.

Comment: no, I am not providing any password. I have tried the remote desktop passowrd, but still the same issue.

Comment: let me show the error message

Answer (score 0):

The Uri should be your Cluster Name, not Username, like:

```
var hadoop = Hadoop.Connect(new Uri("https://clustername.azurehdinsight.net"), "username", "password");
var config = new HadoopJobConfiguration();

            config.InputPath = "input/CodeFiles";
            config.OutputFolder = "output/CodeFiles";
            var result = hadoop.MapReduceJob.ExecuteJob<NamespaceCounterJob>();
```

The cluster name is shown at the top of the detail page in the Azure portal for your cluster.  Also, you don't need to enable RDP to use this method, it's actually the username set for "Hadoop Services" in the configuration tab of the cluster.  Launching a job in this manner makes use of the WebHCat/Templeton endpoint, so RDP is not required.

Comment: sorry, I have posted it wrong. I have input the cluster name. 
and what about the password ?

Comment: The user name and password should be the ones that were set when you created the cluster.  If you no longer have that password, you can turn off and re-enable "Hadoop Services" in the configuration tab and you will be able to reset it. (You have to hit "Save" at the bottom of the page after toggling "Hadoop Services".)

Comment: I have recreated the cluster. Again entered the proper credentials but still the same issue. Should I post the map/reduce functions too ?

Comment: You probably need to include the storage account, container, and key as well, see the example at: http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Running%20jobs%20on%20Azure%20HDInsight%20service

Comment: If you're still having a problem, add the code for your NamespaceCounterJob above, specifically your implementation of the Configure method.

Comment: RickH ... I have provided storage account, container and key. And it connected successfully. Thanks, it was really helpful